# How to compute maximum flow of a network DAG with multiple sources and sinks?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I am working in network coding. I have a problem determining the maximum flow for network directed acyclic graphs having multiple sources or sinks. Can anyone give an example of how to use max-flow-min-cut on a network with multiple sources and sinks and compute the maximum flow?

Examples of the kinds of networks I'm thinking of:

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a specific example ?

Comment: for example 3 source and 4 sinks what is the max flow using the min-cut max-flow theorem.

Comment: I  meant an example which includes the numbers of the flows as well. A graph would be nice.